# Showing a popup view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using STPopup (https://github.com/kevin0571/STPopup) to show a view controller popup. Here's the code

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OneFreeBookViewController") as! OneFreeBookViewController
        
let popupController = STPopupController(rootViewController: vc)
popupController.present(in: self)
popupController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

Unfortunately, the popup is not showing. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warning messages? Are you sure this code is running?

Comment: It's def showing because I see the current screen go into the background and it feels like there is a popup there that's just not showing.

Comment: Will it be displayed correctly if you present the OneFreeBookViewController in the old-fashioned way (e.g. without the StPopupController)?

Comment: @LouisaScheinost - use `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect the layout. See if that tells you what's wrong.